# How to find all document by association Mongoid 4

Tags: mongoid, mongoid4

I have a model `Tag` which potentially belongs to several other models, but at the moment only one model `Todo` which in turn belongs to `User` like so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field: name,  type: String
  has_many :todos
end

class Todo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field: name,  type: String
  belongs_to :user
end

class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field: name,  type: String
  belongs_to :todos
end
```

How can I query all `Tags` that belongs to a particular user?  I've written the following:

```
todo_ids = Todo.where(user_id: '86876876787')
```

and then:

```
tags = Tag.where('todo_id.in': todo_ids)
```

But those didn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two things:

1. Mongoid isn't ActiveRecord so it won't know what to do with `todo_ids` in the `Tag` query.
2. `'todo_id.in'` is a field path that is trying to look at the `in` field inside a `todo_id` hash, this isn't a use of MongoDB's `$in` operator.

You can only work with one collection at a time so to fix the first one, you need to pull an array of IDs out of MongoDB:

```
todo_ids = Todo.where(user_id: '86876876787').pluck(:id)
# -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To fix the second one, use the `$in` operator:

```
tags = Tag.where(todo_id: { '$in': todo_ids })
tags = Tag.where(:todo_id.in => todo_ids)
tags = Tag.in(todo_id: todo_ids)
#...
```